# How to validate all validation rules for a Sitecore item programmatically

Tags: item

Is there any way to validate all validation rules for all fields for an item programmatically ?

We are trying to publish items programmatically, hence we would like to run all the validation rules applicable as per the item template to check, if the sitecore item has no validation errors. IS there anything available out of the sitecore to check this for an item ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/8261765/4015994

Comment: Thanks for the response Marcel, this explains on how to validate an item with a specific validation. In our case, we would like to check any item for all the validation for all the fields to check if the item is in valid state as per https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/102/sitecore-experience-platform/validate-an-item.html

Comment: Try these methods from the `Sitecore.Data.Validators.ValidatorManager` class: `GetGlobalValidatorsForItem()`, `GetItemValidators()`, and `Validate()`